# String.Format vs ToString and using InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting, data-conversion

I am a little confused here.

What should I use

```
Console.WriteLine((val/1085).ToString("N"));

VS

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N}", (val/1085)));
```

Also how do I fit the InvariantCulture? ANY BEST PRACTICES :)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Actually I prefer a third form:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N}", val / 1085);
```

`Console.WriteLine` can do the `String.Format` for you.

`Console.WriteLine` does not allow you to supply a culture. If that is what you want, you will still have to use `String.Format`. As in:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N}", 123456789);
```

I do not recommend using that because international users will have trouble reading that. To me `123,456,789.00` looks strange.

Comment: Where do I fit the  InvariantCulture? and for a number like 34345435 how can I get the output 34,345,435

Comment: I just want to represent 34345435 as 34,345,435

Answer (score 4):

For formatting + culture I prefer:

```
 .ToString("####0.00",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or

```
.ToString("N",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a way to get a conversion which is **not** dependent on the language settings of your PC, here's an invariant and generic way to solve that.

**Syntax:**

```
.ToStringInvariant(format)
.ToStringInvariant()
```

Technically, it is a generic extension method, defined as follows:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static IFormatProvider inv 
                   = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat;

    public static string ToStringInvariant<T>(this T obj, string format=null)
    {
        return (format == null) ? System.FormattableString.Invariant($"{obj}") 
                                : String.Format(inv, $"{{0:{format}}}", obj);
    }
}
```

Its usage is simple, just use `.ToStringInvariant()` instead of `.ToString()`. Note that it works for any data type.

Optionally, you can pass a format too, like for example `.ToStringInvariant("N")`, just as you are used to to it with `.ToString("N")`.
Note that in that case the extension method uses String.Format internally.

You can see the difference if you have a different culture for the number format, like in Germany we have comma instead of a decimal point. That means on a PC with German culture settings:

```
void Main()
{
    var val = 2456.5;
    Console.WriteLine((val/1085).ToString("N"));
    Console.WriteLine((val/1085).ToStringInvariant("N"));
    Console.WriteLine((val/1085).ToStringInvariant("0.000"));
    Console.WriteLine((val/1085).ToStringInvariant());
}
```

it would output:

> **2,26** 
> 2.26 
> 2.264 
> 2.26405529953917

The first output is dependent to the language settings of your PC, which is correct, because `.ToString` uses the current culture (German settings).

But the other ones are using `.ToStringInvariant` which always uses the invariant culture, which is the English number format regardless of the Windows settings.

**Note:** Especially for **date formatting,** I have provided a different extension method, which you can find [here (Parse string to DateTime in C# properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465222/1016343).

---

More information:
[FormattableString.Invariant(FormattableString) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This is equivalent to using `.ToString()` but the question is asking about `.ToString("N")`. Your string interpolation should be like this: `$"{obj:N}"`. (Maybe you'd want to pass format "N" as a parameter though.)

Comment: @intrepidis - Good point, I have improved the extension method so you can now do that too.

Answer (score 1):

In a datetime it's okay to use both. I rather like to use and see the first solution (ofcourse with missing parenthesis).

The String.Format is much more usefull when you have some string with a gaps for some kind of parameters. Then it's a killer method, which really nicely help you to organize your code.