# Parse time string to decimal?

Tags: c#

In .Net, is there a way to convert, say, `'2:45'` to the decimal 2.75?

ex:

```
decimal d = TimeToDecimal("2:45");
Console.WriteLine(d);

//output is 2.75
```

It should throw an exception if invalid data, ex, minutes < 0 < 60 or not in the h:m format.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5366285/82682

Comment: Totally. The "hard" part is `DateTime.Parse()` that will throw the required exception. The rest is about dividing by 60. This is a dupe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following will output `2.75`:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse("2:45");
decimal d = (decimal) time.TotalHours;

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Note that the [`TimeSpan.TotalHours` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) is of type `double`, not `decimal`.

From the documentation for the [`TimeSpan.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx), it will throw an `OverflowException` if "At least one of the days, hours, minutes, or seconds components is outside its valid range", so that should take care of input validation for you.  See also the [`TimeSpan.TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.tryparse.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
private decimal TimeToDecimal(string Time)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Time);
    decimal result = dt.Hour+ (dt.Minute / 60.0m);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you want it to read: `decimal result = dt.Hour + (dt.Minute / 60.0m);`

Comment: I suppose the best solution would be `decimal result = dt.Hour + (dt.Minute / 60.0m) + (dt.Second / 3600.0m);`