# Extract date in yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss format from a string

Tags: c#, regex, date

I have the following string

```
\\server\f$\direct1\205486060518032015-05-28 150931.rtf
```

Which contains a date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss`

Now I have managed to extract that string using a Regular Expression

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{6}");

di = new DirectoryInfo(Location);

var fileList = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (FileInfo fi in fileList)
{
     EngineEvent(this, new EngineEventProperties(String.Format("Filename: {0}", fi.FullName)));
     DateTime fileDate = DateTime.Now;

     Match mat = rgx.Match(fi.FullName);
.
.
.

}
```

The Match contains the expected string '2015-05-28 150931'

However when I try and use the following code to convert it to a DateTime

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(fi.FullName, "yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fileDate))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Date : {0}", fileDate);
};
```

It returns false, using ParseExact fails saying the string does not contain a date.

So how can I do the conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# DateTime to "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025361/c-sharp-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-format)

Comment: I'm not sure we need to know how you get the date string? This questions boils down to *how do I turn this string into a date*. The other stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Liam it's relevant because the OP is passing the wrong value to `ParseExact`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss"
```

`HH` is for 24 hour time format, `hh` is for 12 hour format.  `15` doesn't fit in a 12 hour time format, hence the failure.

Give it a shot:

```
DateTime temp;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("2015-05-28 150931", "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out temp))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Date : {0}", temp);
};
```

always good to bookmark the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page!

Comment: Thanks - I had another error in the code in that I was using fi.filename when I should have been using mat.Value - but it was the format that was wrong so your suggestion was what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to parse the full name, not just the matched part.  Try

```
Match mat = rgx.Match(fi.FullName);

if (mat.success)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(mat.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fileDate))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Date : {0}", fileDate);
    };
}
else
{
    // no natch found...
}
```

Also changed the hour match to 24-hour (`HH`) as identified by @Jonesy