# Can't convert DateTime to string

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I'm trying to convert a `DateTime` to a string but actually the `dt` variable passed in the `getFixtures` method is underlined in red.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Calendar.SelectedDate.Value.ToString(), "ddMMyyyy",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

fixtures.getFixtures(dt);
```

Error:

> Can't convert DateTime to string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I _strongly_ suspect `Calendar.SelectedDate.Value` is _already_ a `DateTime` I never heard such an error or exception message before. On which line you get this? What is the complete message? What `fixtures.getFixtures(dt)` do? And you need to assign to something what `ToString` method returns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you want pass a string to the `getFixtures` but actually you are passing the `dt` which is a `DateTime`.

`dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");` does not change the `dt` to `string`, so you should save it's output to a string and use that string. Here is the code:

```
var stringDt = dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

fixtures.getFixtures(stringDt );
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code:

```
dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
fixtures.getFixtures(dt);
```

If you want to pass string representation of datetime inside a method, change it to :

```
fixtures.getFixtures(dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of,`dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
    fixtures.getFixtures(dt);`

use

```
string dttime=dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
fixtures.getFixtures(dttime);
```

using `dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy")` 
   does not converts dt to string, it just returns a new string, dt remains datetime as it was.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old way but it works. I added to the model.

private string _displayDate;

```
    [Display(Name="Display Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string DisplayDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(_displayDate);
            return dt.ToShortDateString();
        }
        set { _displayDate = value; }

    }
```

//Displays: 3/2/1996