# DateTime.ParseExact() - DateTime pattern 'y' appears more than once with different values

Tags: c#, datetime

I have spent a day trying to get `DateTime.ParseExact()` to work based on this correctly answered question at [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp) however, I cannot get the answer to work.

Here is my code:

```
string testDateRaw = @"2014-05-21 10:08:15.965";
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.yyy";
DateTime testDate = DateTime.ParseExact(testDateRaw, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
System.Console.WriteLine(testDate);
```

Error:

> DateTime pattern 'y' appears more than once with different values.

Note: error reported in original version of the post does not show up in this sample, but may be related:

> "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string before putting each variable into the DateTime object."

Comment: Replace `.yyy` with `.fff`

Comment: Congratulation, this the SO's 1,000,000th question on the same topic without reading necessary doc.....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx BTW: I googled this `datetime custom string` and posted the first link, if you care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`

```
string testDateRaw = @"2014-05-21 10:08:15.965";
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
DateTime testDate = DateTime.ParseExact(testDateRaw, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
System.Console.WriteLine(testDate);
```

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The error I get with that code is the following:

> DateTime pattern 'y' appears more than once with different values.

It's pretty self-explanatory. Looking at [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), you need to use `.fff` here:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.fff"
```

`yyy` is: *The year, with a minimum of three digits*, but since you already have `yyyy` in your pattern, you get the duplicate specifier error.

Answer (score 1):

Your format is wrong, you used y twice.

```
string testDateRaw = @"2014-05-21 10:08:15.965";
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.fff";
DateTime testDate = DateTime.ParseExact(testDateRaw, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
System.Console.WriteLine(testDate);
```