# Converting a localized string to datetime

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, format

I'd like to convert a localized string (preferably any supported language) to a datetime object.
The string is for example (in dutch): woensdag 3 juni 2015 9:12:14 uur CEST

The localized string is always of the same format: [day name] [day] [month] [year] [hour] [minute] [second] [literal word for hour] [time zone]
The string provided to the program can't be changed on the host application (not enough privileges).

I've read that in C# .NET I need to use something like an [InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) object to change a DateTime object to a localized string date.

Is it however possible to go the other way around? If so is it possible with my requirements above?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something like DateTime.Parse("donderdag 3 juni 2015 9:12:14 uur CEST", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture): ? That should give you a usable datetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Liam Partially true, although OP asks specifically in relation to language-specific representations, whereas the post you reference is for a general date-time structure.

Comment: The duplicate is more because this doesn't show any research effort. The OP should be able to easily take the dupe question and try themselves. Then if they have a **specific question** (which this is not) then they can ask that

Comment: Very true, point taken. I rest my case.

Comment: You _can't_ parse this string because it is **not** a valid `DateTime` in Gregorian Calendar. [June 3th 2015](http://www.calendar-365.com/calendar/2015/June.html) is Wednesday, not Thursday (which is "donderdag" in Dutch)

Comment: The invariant culture is the exact *opposite* of what you want here. You need the right format string, with the right culture, which certainly *isn't* the invariant culture.

Comment: and you have no information about the culture ? So the date could be parsed specific to that culture ?

Comment: You can parse the string with appropriate CultureInfo, it supports localized format.

Comment: @SonerGönül that is indeed correct, my mistake. It has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is time zone *awareness*. It does not have *any* information about time zone. That's why you need to parse this `CEST` part as a literal delimiter. (*AFAIK*, there is no way to parse them other than escape it) Looks like `uur` means "hour" in english, you need to specify it as a literal as well.

Then, you can parse it your string with `dddd d MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss 'uur CEST'"` format and `nl-BE` culture like;

```
string s = "woensdag 3 juni 2015 9:12:14 uur CEST";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dddd d MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss 'uur CEST'", 
                          CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-BE"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt); // 03/06/2015 09:12:14
}
```

You *definitely* not wanna use `InvariantCulture` to parse this string. This culture is *english-based* and keep [`DayNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.daynames.aspx) with their english names as Wednesday etc..

By the way, Nodatime has [`ZonedDateTime` structure](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime.htm) and looks like it supports a time zone with it's [`Zone` property](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/P_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime_Zone.htm).

Comment: Accepted you answer as it is a more clean one (does a TryParse and escapes, delimits literals)

Comment: @Dragon54 Great! Check the edit I did about Nodatime part.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue thanks to the comments placed underneath the original question that was asked.

By using string replacements I can ditch the localized 'uur' which stands for hour in dutch along with the CEST.

The following code did the trick for me:

```
CultureInfo nlculture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");
string test = "woensdag 3 juni 2015 9:12:14";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "dddd d MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss", nlculture);
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString());
```

To come back on one of the requirements, which was having it support multiple languages. I can (after checking again with the things I can work with) capture the used language, thus letting me able to support multiple languages.

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work.  I'm getting an error but I think it is due to an old version of VS installed on my computer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact("3 june 2015 9:12:14 PM GMT", "d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string y = x.ToString("d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt K", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL"));
            string dutchTimeString = "3 juni 2015 9:12:14 uur CEST";

            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dutchTimeString, "d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt Z", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE"));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First, this does not answer the question. Your string does not have any AM/PM designator but you use `tt` in your `ParseExact` method. That does not make sense. And second, your string does not even the same with OP. Third, using `Z` with `DateTime` parsing is not recommended. It will be better to use it with `DateTimeOffset` instead.

Comment: uur is AM/PM designator.  CEST is GMT which is offset zero.  If you used google translation you would of found this out.

Comment: No. [`uur` means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uur) `hours` in Dutch. It is not a designator or something. `nl-BE` culture has an empty strings for them (at least in .NET 4 and Win7). And your string is _still_ not the same with OP's. `CEST` offset is not relevant because `DateTime` structure does not support _any_ time zone information.

Comment: If I go to google translation and include uur and then remove uur the PM translation comes and goes.  it may translate to hours, but it seems the meaning is actually PM.  I think the real reason for this posting is the fact that the Net Library doesn't properly support the AM/PM (tt) in Dutch.