# How to convert the string 3.0E-4 to decimal

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a string `"3.0E-4"`, it is supposed to be a decimal number.

Please advise how to convert to a decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`AllowExponent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) and [`AllowDecimalPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) styles combination with [`decimal.Parse` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) like;

```
var result = decimal.Parse("3.0E-4", 
                           NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this looks obsoleted, I don't see an overload with CultureInfo.

Comment: @khoailang Obsolete o.O? It is _definitely_ not and [`Decimal.Parse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx.aspx) overload exist since .NET 2.0. Are you _really_ sure about that? What is your environment?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
decimal x = Decimal.Parse("3.0E-4", NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
```

or like

```
decimal x = Decimal.Parse("3.0E-4", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`.TryParse`** avoids exception handling (`.Parse` will throw and exception if parsing fails):

```
void Main()
{
    var str="3.0E-4";
    float d;
    if (float.TryParse(str, out d))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("d = " + d.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid decimal!");
    }
}
```

[image]

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465222/1016343) for more info why you should prefer TryParse.

Comment: thanks, I tried this with the decimal, can not parse the string, the tryparse returns false!

Comment: Right, you have to use `float`. For me, `decimal` was not working as well - that's why I posted this. @khoailang