# I need to identify a particular date time format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

What format is the following date time string in? I need to read it in C#.

```
2010-09-29T02:40:00.2291503+05:30
```

Comment: Looks like `ISO 8601`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Did you try anything to parse the date? E.g. looking on https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp?

Comment: Parsing the format with `DateTime.Parse` works fine, did you even try this?

Comment: What is your question _exactly_? Do you wanna get which format of your string? That's not possible since there can be ambiguous situations for it. Do you wanna parse it to `DateTime` instead which you mean by _I need to read it in C#_? If so, what have you tried to solve your problem? It is totally unclear what you asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string by using `DateTime.Parse(string)`

```
DateTime.Parse("2010-09-29T02:40:00.2291503+05:30");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the DateTime with [RoundTrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip)

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier (and the
>   "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK" custom format string) takes
>   advantage of the three ways that ISO 8601 represents time zone
>   information to preserve the Kind property of DateTime values:
>
> - The time zone component of DateTimeKind.Local date and time values is an offset from UTC (for example, +01:00, -07:00). All
>     DateTimeOffset values are also represented in this format.
> - The time zone component of DateTimeKind.Utc date and time values uses "Z" (which stands for zero offset) to represent UTC.
> - DateTimeKind.Unspecified date and time values have no time zone information.

---

Here's the example of use of DateTime.Kind:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       DateTime dat = new DateTime(2009, 6, 15, 13, 45, 30, 
                                   DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
       Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) --> {0:O}", dat, dat.Kind); 

       DateTime uDat = new DateTime(2009, 6, 15, 13, 45, 30, 
                                    DateTimeKind.Utc);
       Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) --> {0:O}", uDat, uDat.Kind);

       DateTime lDat = new DateTime(2009, 6, 15, 13, 45, 30, 
                                    DateTimeKind.Local);
       Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) --> {0:O}\n", lDat, lDat.Kind);

       DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(lDat);
       Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {0:O}", dto);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM (Unspecified) --> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000
//    6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM (Utc) --> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000Z
//    6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM (Local) --> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000-07:00
//    
//    6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -07:00 --> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000-07:00
```