# How to convert 'dd-MM-yyyy' to 'yyyy-MM-dd'?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL DateTime column that I need to query using C#. The problem is that when I try to query the column with the DateTime format of 'dd-MM-yyyy' it doesn't bring back any data but it does when I use the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. I am wondering how I can convert my DateTime into that format?

Eg:

```
string yyyyMMdd = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

//Insert code to parse into yyyy-MM-dd DateTime format-
```

This gets the format I want in a `string`, but the column is a `DateTime` and every time I try to parse it, it returns back to the 'dd-MM-yyyy' format.

Man, stack overflow is so fickle. This question is different as I'm not asking how to format a DateTime into a different cultures format. I'm asking how to format a DateTime from the 'yy-MM-yyyy' to the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.

Why the downvotes? Honestly.

Comment: You don't "parse a DateTime", you format it. Parsing is something you do to strings. The DateTime value does not have a format, the act of converting it to a string picks a format. If you want to have the DateTime value shown a specific way you need to take control over the formatting. Please clarify what the question really is.

Comment: You say, "I'm not asking how to format a DateTime", and then, "I'm asking how to format a DateTime from the 'yy-MM-yyyy' to the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format". It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this at all, you should be using parameterised queries and just pass the `DateTime` as a parameter...

Comment: @TrevorPilley Urgh, this is exactly what I'm doing in EF.

Comment: Your solution is wrong, dont waste your time to do this. Your question should be how to parse a datetime value to SQL.

Comment: @Enigmativity Okay, I'll edit it. I am asking how to format a DateTime but every post I've been pointed at doesn't answer my question. I know how to parse a DateTime, just not how to format it into a different culture

Comment: I'm lost. Since you're using EF anyway, shouldn't the code take DateTime as it is without issue? Can u post the exception (if any) and the complete code?

Comment: @AndrewKilburn - There is no "different culture" for a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` is just a value type. It's only when you convert from a string or convert to a string that cultures get involved. The value of a `DateTime` is simply held in a `private UInt64 dateData;` field.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn - You're getting down-votes because people are trying to help you, yet you respond with "stack overflow is so fickle" and "Urgh" and "Why the downvotes? Honestly."

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Parse() will try figure out the format of the given date, and it usually does a good job. If you can guarantee dates will always be in a given format then you can use ParseExact():

```
//string s = "2011-03-21";
string yyyyMMdd = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yyyyMMdd , "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5366311/4985572)

Answer (score -1):

You could always try using:

```
DateTime testdate = DateTime.Now;

testdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

and just set the DateTime to whatever date and time you may need.

Comment: No because this would return a string, not a DateTime

Comment: This might help you [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc165448.aspx)