# "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" by getting a value of date from JS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I have this code to retrieve a date

```
var _Sdate = new Date(Date.parse($("#LSDate").val()));
```

It been loop thats why I got 2 dates.

[image: Result for day]

And now I am getting this error:

[image: Error].

I have tried to set `DateTime date1` but I got also an error.

Comment: Your image shows a variable `date1` in the debugger, is that the string you want to parse?

Comment: How do you want to convert two different dates in one string to one `DateTime`? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: How do you expect to cram two date-strings into one DateTime instance? If you exercise a bit of critical thinking about your issue and what you need to accomplish...

Comment: @diiN_ I just want to get the dates :(

Answer (score 1):

This date format is not what a .Net [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) object can parse, you actually have to make your date looks more like: `2011-03-21 13:26`

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp) for expected Datetime data input to parse a string, there are multiple string representations taht can be parsed.
(also in this [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), at section *Converting strings to DateTime values*)

Comment: Yes, would be easier to change what you send from the JS side instead of complicating the parsing part on .Net side

Comment: What else code should i use?. I don't much codes to use.

Comment: If your Js date is a date object, you can try `date.toUTCString()`

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Mon Aug 1 2016 00:00:00 GMT 0800 (China

... etc ... is nowhere near a valid DateTime.

Hence the invalid DateTime error on parsing.

Where are you getting this value from?

[DateTime.Parse Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx)

The .Net framework, when given a string, needs to understand how to turn that into a DateTime object, and it can't do that with what you've provided it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support guys. I found a solution to while doing an experiment on my codes. I use this

```
 var _Sdate = new Date(Date.parse($("#LSDate").val()));
 var _EndDate = new Date(Date.parse($("#LEDate").val()));
 var cbxAM = $('.cbox_leave_half').is(':checked');
 var cbxPM = $('.cbox_leave_halfPM').is(':checked');
 var IsAM, IsPM, date1 = "";
    var _halfdayCount = "";
            var x = 0;
            var getfullhrAM = "12:00:00 AM"
            var chkdateAM = "", chkdatePM = "";
            if (parseInt(_hashalfday) > 0) {
                while (_Sdate <= _EndDate) {
                    var fulldate = (_Sdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + _Sdate.getDate() + "/" + _Sdate.getFullYear();
                    var getcompile = fulldate + " " + getfullhrAM;
                    if (_Sdate != _EndDate) {
                        _halfdayCount = _halfdayCount + HalfDayrowsObj[x].HalfDay + ",";
                        date1 = date1 + getcompile + ",";
                     if (HalfDayrowsObj[x].HalfDay == true) {
                            if (cbxAM == true) {
                               chkdateAM =  getcompile;
                            } else {
                                IsAM = false;
                            }
                       }
                    }
                    else {
                        _halfdayCount = _halfdayCount + HalfDayrowsObj[x].HalfDay;
                        NofDays = parseFloat(NofDays) + parseFloat('.5');
                        date1 = date1 + +HalfDayrowsObj[x].HalfDay;
                    }
                    x++;
                    _Sdate.setDate(_Sdate.getDate() + 1);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will be pleased to offer my little js-function for getting any js date into acceptable format for C#, SQL Server and PHP,MYSql

```
var jsdate = new Date(Date.parse($("#LSDate").val()));
//jsdate is java-script date object
//Before you send it to use at server, plz make it a string as following
var _Sdate = getDateTimeString(_Sdate);

//Now you get _Ssdate acceptable for c#,sql it would be like '2016-08-01 02:13:06'

function getDateTimeString(dt) {
    var dt = new Date();
    var m = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = dt.getFullYear();
    var d = dt.getDate();
    var mm = dt.getMinutes();
    var h = dt.getHours();
    var s = dt.getSeconds();
    if (m < 10)
        m = "0" + m;
    if (d < 10)
        d = "0" + d;

    if (h < 10)
        h = "0" + h;
    if (mm < 10)
        mm = "0" + mm;
    if (s < 10)
        s = "0" + s;
    return y + "-" + m + "-" + d + " " + h + ":" + mm + ":" + s;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the concern however how do I get the 12:00:00 in my controller? Because in datetime the time is set to 12:00:00