# How to split string with two time and convert to datetime

Tags: c#

How can i split my `string` into two `datetime`,

```
string schedulemonday=10:00am - 1:00pm;
```

I want to split the two time into two `datetime` datatype like

```
DateTime starttime=10:00am;
DateTime endtime=1:00pm;
```

Comment: Take a look at String.Split and DateTime.Parse and/or new DateTime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second) and show us the code and a specific problem if you get stuck.

Comment: Why would you start with a Date/Time in a `string` ? There is no such thing as `DateTime starttime=10:00am;`

Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

first break up the string to get the separate date strings

```
string schedulemonday = "10:00am - 1:00pm"; 
string[] parts = schedulemonday.Split(' ');
```

part[0] and part[2] should contain the start and end times, respectively

then see this post to convert a string to a datetime

[Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)