# Search a text file for a date and enumerate through the dates outputting only dates that are higher than the first date

Tags: c#

I am reading a text file to a list and, adding line numbers to the output. I want to search for a date in the format of MM/Day/Year and output it to console. If the next date in the text file is the same as the last one found then I do not want to output it, I only want to output the date that is later than the last. I am new to programming and have searched the site for date search code but haven't found something I understand. Here is my current code.

```
    internal class LineInformation
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string Line { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {var fileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "doc.txt");

        var theWholeFile = File.ReadLines(fileName)
            .Select((line, index) => new LineInformation { Line = line, Index = index }).ToList();
```

Now I don't know how to search specifically for the aforementioned date format and write it to console. How would I declare a date format like MM/Day/Year then say something like;

```
    if(line.Contains(date)=>1stdate)
    {Console.WriteLine(date)}
```

Comment: id probably start with regex for stripping down to lines with dates in, unless thats going to be all, and then converting the date regex found and comparing.

Comment: Thank you @BugFinder, I will look at regex and see what I can learn. I don't really understand what your saying but I will go and read-up on it.

Comment: You haven't included input and desired output. I am guessing you just have to find datetime in each line (`Substring()` if position is known, `Split`+index/logic or regex otherwise), and then just [parse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5366285/1997232) it and compare with instance of `DateTime()` (e.g. `var firstDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);`).

Comment: @Sinatr Sorry if my description is not very clear, I want to search a text file for dates in the format of mm/dd/yyy. I know how to read a text file and search for keywords but I don't know how to search for a date format of mm/dd/yyyy. There are a lot of repeated dates in the file but I only want all dates once (not repeated). Then when I `Console.WriteLine` I would like to see all dates without repeated dates.

Comment: It may not be easy, best is if you show piece of this input file so someone can give you good suggestion. There should be a *pattern* to recognize datetime (e.g. generally you can try to use those too slashes: mm`/`dd`/`yyyy as well as knowledge such as before first slash is number between 01-12, then another one 01-31 and then 4 digit years. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to compare the current date with the last one,and ignore the current if last one was greater then you can do it like this. Hope it helps

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,     "doc.txt");
var theWholeFile = File.ReadLines(fileName)
    .Select((line, index) => new LineInformation { Line = line, Index = index}).ToList();
var lastValue = string.Empty;
foreach (var x in theWholeFile)
{
   //The first date will be printed no matter what
    if (lastValue == string.Empty)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(x.Line,"mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        lastValue = x.Line;
    }
    else
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(x.Line) > DateTime.Parse(lastValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(x.Line, "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        lastValue = x.Line;
    }

}
```