# Parsing Date Time in C#, Getting wrong output

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse the date by using below code

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(datetoconvert,"dd/mm/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

but its output is wrong, the datetoconvert in above code is `30/Mar/2017` but output is `29/Jan/2017`

looking forward for your valuable answers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lowercase `mm` means minute, use `MM`

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(datetoconvert,"dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

If you want to output it as `30/Mar/2017`(different topic):

```
string result = mydate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But note that [`/` has a special meaning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#The) too(in `Parse` and `ToString`). It will be replaced with your current cultures date-separator which seems to be `/` but fails with a different. You can avoid it by specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or by masking it by wrapping it with apostrophes:

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact(datetoconvert,"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: `MM` matches integer values (1-12) for month, not the abbreviated name

Answer (score 7):

replace

```
"dd/mm/yyyy"
```

with

```
"dd/MMM/yyyy"
```

because `"Jan"` is matched by `MMM` instead of `mm` (for minutes)

**Reference**

> "MMM" The abbreviated name of the month.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The date format is wrong. try **"dd/MM/yyyy"** instead of **"dd/mm/yyyy"**

If you need abbrivated month name, use **"dd/MMM/yyyy"**