# Parsing a string to DateTime type when the layout is RightToLeft

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I want to parse a string value that is displayed in a label and then insert that value along with other values to a table in a database .. so I have the stored procedure that **contains the insert** statement and a method that performs **performs the insert** statement and finally I call the method in my button click event to perform the insert method but it gives me an exception message "Input string was not in correct format" and a tip which is "Parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into datetime object"

the call of this method in the button click event is:

```
DateTime billDateTime = DateTime.Parse(pBillDateLbl.Text);
purchaseCashBill.InsertGeneralCashBillInfo(billDateTime, pBillUserNameTxt.Text, Convert.ToInt32(pBillCompCmbo.SelectedValue), pBillCompCmbo.SelectedText, Convert.ToDouble(pBillItmTtlPrice.Text), true);
```

I have also tried to pare the string using this way also but the same exception appears:

```
DateTime billDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
   pBillDateLbl.Text, 
  "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

and the value of the label is in the form of:

```
pBillDateLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

appears like this in my application :05:45:22 05/04/2017

Comment: what's the value of `pBillDateLbl.Text`

Comment: what is your input value (the string)?

Comment: It sounds like the problem has nothing to do with the SQL, and is purely about the parsing - so please provide a [mcve] showing that, including hard-coded input. It's important to perform diagnostic work to reduce the problem to a minimal example before posting: if you never get as far as the `InsertGeneralCashBillInfo` method, then that's not relevant IMO.

Comment: The only code you should have in your question is `DateTime billDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(pBillDateLbl.Text, "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`.  All other code and details are irrelevant.

Comment: @fubo the input to the label is in a form of day-month-year hour:muinets:seconds
pBillDateLbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

Comment: @MohammedShfq -- No, what is the *actual value* at the time the exception is being thrown?  Copy and paste it here.

Comment: @rory.ap  this is the value 05:43:34 04/05/2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the value you provided in your comments -- `05:43:34 04/05/2017`, you can clearly see that your format string is in the wrong order.  Also, it contains an extra space at the end.  Try this:

```
DateTime billDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(pBillDateLbl.Text, "hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: it gives me an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @MohammedShfq -- did you use the format string I provided in this answer?  The code runs just fine for me.

Comment: Yes I took it and I changed x variable by the label name and it gave me that exception

Comment: And you're positive that the value of `pBillDateLbl.Text` is *exactly* `"05:43:34 04/05/2017"`?  No extra spaces, etc.

Comment: Yes there is only one space between the time portion and date portion

Comment: only one note that I don't know if it means something to this process but I should say that the property of RightToLeft=Yes and RightToLeftLayout=True in my Form property