# Convert String to DateTime Asp.Net

Tags: c#, datetime

How to convert a string such as `"10/19/2017 12:00:00 AM"` into a DateTime? I used `Convert.ToDateTime()` but It gives an error as;

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How to fix?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("10/19/2017 12:00:00 AM")` or ParseExact

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **`ParseExact`**

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("10/19/2017 12:00:00 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Since `AM` and `PM` designators are used for [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), I think it would be better to use `hh` instead of `HH` specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have specified formatting to parse, you need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// DateTime.ParseExact
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("10/19/2017 12:00:00 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// DateTime.TryParseExact
DateTime.TryParseExact("10/19/2017 12:00:00 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

Comment: Since `AM` and `PM` designators are used for [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), I think it would be better to use `hh` instead of `HH` specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

```
 String MyString= "10/19/2017 12:00:00 AM";
        DateTime MyDateTime = new DateTime();
        MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Format goes as below**

d - Numeric day of the month without a leading zero.

dd - Numeric day of the month with a leading zero.

ddd - Abbreviated name of the day of the week.

dddd - Full name of the day of the week.

f,ff,fff,ffff,fffff,ffffff,fffffff - 
    Fraction of a second. The more Fs the higher the precision.

h - 12 Hour clock, no leading zero.

hh - 12 Hour clock with leading zero.

H - 24 Hour clock, no leading zero.

HH - 24 Hour clock with leading zero.

m - Minutes with no leading zero.
mm - Minutes with leading zero.

M - Numeric month with no leading zero.

MM - Numeric month with a leading zero.

MMM - Abbreviated name of month.

MMMM - Full month name.

s - Seconds with no leading zero.
ss - Seconds with leading zero.

t - AM/PM but only the first letter. 
tt - AM/PM ( a.m. / p.m.)

y - Year with out century and leading zero.

yy - Year with out century, with leading zero.

yyyy - Year with century.

zz - Time zone off set with +/-.

Comment: You don't need `DateTime MyDateTime = new DateTime();` because you will create new date anyway `DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(...` will be enough.