# How do I parse date-time strings with various characters as date delimiters?

Tags: c#, date-formatting

**NOTE** - Yes, the question from 2011 that my question is suggested as a dupe of, [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp), has answers I could use, but Zohar's answer below is by far the best of all of them, and possibly takes into consideration advances in C# that did not exist 7 years ago.  Thus the question is indeed a dupe, but the best answer is found HERE, not THERE.

I'm reading the EXIF information in digital photographs taken with a camera, and photographs scanned by my scanner, and am finding that while the Canon scanner formats the date with "/", the Fujifilm camera formats them with ":". I need to parse these strings to DateTime, and would like a nifty short way of doing it. I don't know if other makers provide EXIF data with yet different date formats, such as hyphens ("-"), periods (".") or some other delimiter, and how I am supposed to allow for all of them?  I know one way to do it (try-catch blocks looking for FormatException), but is there a better way?

*By the way*, the [EXIF standard](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-Translation-2016-E.pdf) specifies yyyy:mm:dd, with the colon (:) for delimiter, but as mentioned, my Canon scanner (Canoscan 9000F Mk II) uses the slant (/). Presumably other makers could use a different delimiter.

The camera is providing: "2008:10:06 16:00:07"

For which I can do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or try to catch several variants as follows:

```
try
{
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    try
    {
        dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        try
        {
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
}
```

Don't get me started on all the rest of the formats that *could* occur!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @crunchy No, that's a very general question about parsing one format.  This is about parsing multiple formats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Be very careful** with ambiguous formats. If one device returns `yyyy/MM/dd` and the other returns `yyyy/dd/MM` you might find yourself returning wrong results.

I would recommend [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ParseExact` in a try..catch block.

The overload I've linked to can take an array of strings as possible formats, and will parse successfully if the input string matches exactly (at least) one of them.

```
var formats = new string[] 
{
    "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss",
    "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
};

DateTime dt;
if(
   DateTime.TryParseExact(
       str, 
       formats, 
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
       DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, // Please note AssumeLocal might be wrong here...
       out dt)
 ) // parsed successfully...
```