# C# device input on date format

Tags: c#, io

I am reading an input from a device on a comm port, that is  a date in the following format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" to a string value. I am trying to format the date to show "ddMMyyyy hh:mm:ss". I have tried the following but get the error below code:

> (input value is "31/08/2018 02:32")

```
        public string ParseLine(string Line)
        {
            var input = Line.Split(',');
            var dateTime = DateTime.Parse (input[0]);
            var Action = input[1] == "1" ? "ONL" : "OFL";
            var readerAddr = input[1] == "1" ? "S" : "T";
            var TagType = input[2];
            var TagNum = input[3].Substring(TagType.Length);

            return $"{Action},{TagNum},{readerAddr},{dateTime:ddMMyyyy hh:mm:ss}";
        }
```

Any advise will be appreciated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I assume `input[0]` has a valid value.

Comment: What is the value of `Line`?

Comment: There error message tells you exactly what's wrong.  Have a look at the value of `input[0]` - edit the question to show us what value you have.

Comment: What culture are you using?  This is a valid UK time format, but if you are anywhere else in the world, this is probably not valid (for example, in the US, the expected format is MM/DD/YYYY).

Comment: Yes input value is a string and it looks like this: dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm I just want it whithout the "/" and add seconds so that it is in this format ddMMyyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: What country is your computer set to?

Comment: @Neil it is set to US

Comment: OK, so do you see what the problem is?  `DateTime.Parse` is trying to parse your `DD/MM/YYYY` string as `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Comment: I have added the solution as an answer below, thanks for all advise and comments!

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime.TryParseExact to check if 'input[0]' has a valid datetime value. Example:

```
public string ParseLine(string Line)
{
   ...
   if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(input[0], "ddMMyyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result))
     {
         //Is not a valid date :C
     }

   Console.WriteLine("Valid date: " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case date time would be in some weird format, you will need to use `DateTime.ParseExact(..)` method like this:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input[0], "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
```

However, your format is one of the accepted ISO formats, so it should work like you wrote down. The best reason why is does not work is that the value of `input[0]` is not what you expect, so at first check what this variable actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone's comments and advise I managed to get it right by using these two methods:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input[0], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and

```
return $"{Action},{TagNum},{readerAddr},{dateTime:ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss}";
```