# c# date time parse from Fri Feb 21 23:07:58 +0000 2020

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have the following date

```
string dateTimeText = @"Fri Feb 21 23:07:58 +0000 2020";
```

I want to *parse* it:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeText, "D M dd HH:mm:ss +ssss yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

this implementation *throws exception*. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings. The  3 letter  abreviation for day is [`ddd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dddSpecifier), and for mounth its [`MMM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#MMM_Specifier) But what is *+ssss* suppose to be ? May be you mean fraction of seconf [`ffff`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ffffSpecifier) or time zone ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"`

Comment: It does not matter how you shuffle your date input string the answer is still the same ParseExact + check the documentation for Custom format. You can use classical debug jutsu. By cutting your input string in half  on a separator an try that part of parse exact to narrow down to the part you have issue with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if `+ssss` (`+0000`) stands for *TimeZone* (so `+0000` means **GMT**) the pattern is

```
  "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"
```

I.E.

```
  string dateTimeText = "Fri Feb 21 23:07:58 +0000 2020";

  var result = DateTime.ParseExact(
      dateTimeText, 
    @"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", 
      CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

In case `+ssss` and (an corresponding `+0000`) are *fractions of seconds* the pattern will be

```
   "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss' +'FFFF yyyy"
```