# Parsing nested Json data with C#. Could not access inner element consumption

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I can parse up to one nested level but I'm unable to figure out how to read the data in the `consumption_history`. I have been trying different ways to do it but could not get the consumption value.

I can access the `miu_id` and `meter_number` but not the array of `consumption_list`.

**Model:**

```
class JsonModel
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string site_id { get; set; }
        public Endpoint[] endpoints { get; set; }
        public Paging paging { get; set; }
    }

    public class Paging
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
        public object prev { get; set; }
        public string self { get; set; }
    }

    public class Endpoint
    {
        public string miu_id { get; set; }
        public string meter_number { get; set; }
        public Consumption_History[] consumption_hist { get; set; }
    }

    public class Consumption_History
    {
        public DateTime reading_date { get; set; }
        public float consumption { get; set; }
        public float consumption_with_multiplier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Program:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ConsoleApp3\apidataone.json");
    var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel.Rootobject>(json);

    JsonModel.Rootobject rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel.Rootobject>(json);
    rootobject.endpoints = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel.Rootobject>(json).endpoints;

    foreach (JsonModel.Consumption_History ch in rootobject.endpoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ch.consumption);

    }
}
```

**json data:**

```
{
    "site_id":"1",
    "endpoints":
    [{
          "miu_id":"111",
          "meter_number":"88",
          "consumption_history":
          [{
              "reading_date":"2010-02-17T00:00:00", 
              "consumption":1.0, 
              "consumption_with_multiplier":1.0
          }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Your property is named : consumption_hist when in the json it's consumption_hist**ory** add `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "consumption_history")]` like [in this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net). befor the property and voila Online demo => https://dotnetfiddle.net/vIosiq

Answer (score 3):

I have simplified the code a bit, instead of reading from a file I have just put the JSON content in place. This code uses **Newtonsoft.Json** (available via NUGET package), but the way it works is the same for other serializers.

```
// using Newtonsoft.Json;
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{
        'site_id':'1',
        'endpoints':
        [{
              'miu_id':'111',
              'meter_number':'88',
              'consumption_history':        
              [{
                  'reading_date':'2010-02-17T00:00:00',
                  'consumption':1.0,
                  'consumption_with_multiplier':1.0
              }]
        }]
    }";

    dynamic j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
    string site_id = j["site_id"].ToString();
    var endpoints = j["endpoints"];
    foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
    {
        string miu_id = endpoint["miu_id"];
        miu_id.Dump();
        // ...
        var consumption_histories = endpoint["consumption_history"];
        foreach(var consumption in consumption_histories)
        {
            string reading_date = consumption["reading_date"];
            reading_date.Dump();
            // ...
        } // foreach
    } // foreach
}
```

[Run it in .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ft2kBA)

Regarding **JSON:** Whenever there is a `[ ... ]` in the JSON structure, this means there is an array (`{ ... }` stands for an object) - and `[{ ... }]` is an object *inside an array*; both properties and array elements are separated by comma (`,`); *strings* and *property names* need to be enclosed in single quotes (`'...'`). Value assignments are done with a colon (`:`). In JSON, you have either objects, strings or numeric data - these are the only types existing. If you need types, you have to cast properties into the proper types by yourself.

You can access the array either via indexer (like `endpoints[i]` inside a `for` loop), or - as I am assuming - you want to go through every element, in that case a `foreach` loop is easier.

**Note:** To use it in a `for` loop (like `for (int i = 0; i < endpointsLength; i++) { ... }`), you would have to cast `endpoints` and `consumption_histories` into an array type (e.g. via `var endpoints = (object[])j["endpoints"];`) and lose the simplicity `dynamic` provides (for example, then you would need an indexer to access a property like `(endpoints[i])["miu_id"]` to be able to get the value of `miu_id`).

The keyword `dynamic` simplifies things a lot in this case, this way you can keep the "JavaScript-Style" of the C# code (remember JSON comes from the JavaScript world).

If you want to introduce the classes you have declared in C#, this is also possible. For example:

```
foreach (Consumption_History consumption in consumption_histories)
{
    string reading_date = consumption.reading_date.ToString();
    reading_date.Dump();
    // ...
} // foreach
```

You can see, that `reading_date` is now being accessed as C# property, and because it is of type `DateTime`, you need to cast it into a string first. This conversion needs to be done before the `foreach` loop, so you can either change the data type in your class to string to avoid that, or you can use the original code shown above and copy + convert the data into typed versions of your objects (for converting a string into DateTime, you can [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465222/1016343)).

If you rely on the built-in conversion NewtonSoft.JSON provides, you can simply use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json)` instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)`. Note that implicit conversions can throw exceptions.

Also, make sure that the property names in C# and in your JSON file match exactly - if not you can decorate them in C# using attributes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796648/1016343) for a description how to do that) - [xdtTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9260725/xdttransform) found that it is not matching for `consumption_hist`, and mentioned it in the comments.